# Operator polynomials; injective?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, polynomials, operator-theory

Let $p$ be a polynomial, $\sigma:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ an invertible function and $Q$ an operator on functions. If $\sigma(Q)\neq Q$, is it possible to have $p(\sigma(Q))=p(Q)$?

I know for real numbers it is possible, for example, $p(2)=p(-2)$ if $p(x)=x^2$ and $\sigma(x)=2x+6$.

Comment: What is $\sigma$ in your real example? Is it $\sigma(x) = -x$? In that case, doesn't $\sigma(0) = 0$ go against your requirement? And if not, what's stopping you from using the same example for complex numbers?

Comment: It does go against the requirement, but I can't think of a better example; maybe it is not possible even in the real case

Comment: So you meant $p(x) = x^2=p(-x)$

Comment: Yes reuns, so what's the conclusion?

Comment: Can you state your hypotheses precisely?  What kind of function is $\sigma$ supposed to be (continuous?)?  What space of functions does $Q$ act on?

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible.  Just take $p$ to be any constant polynomial.  Or more generally, given any counterexample where you replace $Q$ with a number (such as your example), just take $Q$ to be scalar multiplication by that number.

Comment: Let us exclude constants, I am specifically asking if it is possible for sigma(Q)^k = Q^k , k not zero

Comment: As I said, any example with real numbers immediately gives an example with operators by taking a scalar multiplication operator.

Comment: But taking my real example, (-2Q)^2 is not equal to (-2Q+6)^2

Comment: I don't know how you got those two expressions from your example.  For a really simple example, if $\sigma(x)=-x$ and $Q$ is the identity, then $\sigma(Q)^2=Q^2$.

Comment: I forgot to mention, $\sigma$ is not an involution (not its own inverse), so the example you give does not qualify